# Jenkins Declarative pipeline : How to get files (Which exits in different nodes) data into Arrays

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Through Jenkins Declarative pipeline script, is it possible to read file data and from different nodes ??** 
 
 
Example : 
I've 3 nodes (A to C). 
From A, I need to read file data from all other nodes and need to store in an array, and then From A I need to do some operations from those Array values.
I've tried with the following code.

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    stages{
        stage("Node-C"){
            agent {
                label "Node-C"
            }
            steps{
                sh '''
                   arr1=($(grep -i "docker" /opt/abc/Text1.txt))
                '''
            }
        }
        stage("Node-B"){
            agent {
                label "Node-B"
            }
            steps{
                sh '''
                   arr1+=($(grep -i "docker" /opt/abc/Text1.txt))
                '''
            }
        }
        stage("Node-A"){
            agent {
                label "Node-A"
            }
            steps{
                sh '''
                    arr1+=($(grep -i "docker" /opt/abc/Text1.txt))
                    for i in "${arr1[@]}"
                    do
                       echo "== $i =="
                    done
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above script is printing only Node-A's File data.
But, how we can print Node-B and Node-C data also ?

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable and read values to that variable.

```
def str=''
pipeline{
agent any
stages {
    stage('master'){
        agent {
            label 'master' 
        }
       steps{ 
           script { str +='am in node 1 ' }
       }
    }
    stage('agent'){
        agent {
            label 'agent01' 
        }
       steps{ 
          script{ str += 'and am in node 2' }
       }
    }

     stage('output'){
       steps{ 
           echo "${str}"
       }
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Define array in Jenkinsfile

```
def arr1 = []
```

2 - New variables for the elements of array

```
String element1 = sh (
                        script: 'grep -i "docker" /opt/abc/Text1.txt',
                        returnStdout: true
                   ).trim()
```

3 - Append the elements to the array